# Delete bones via script

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, bones

I want to delete all bones in an armature which contain a specific word but I can't figure out how to. This is the script:

```
import bpy
import fnmatch


ob = bpy.context.object

if ob.type == 'ARMATURE':
    armature = ob.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

for bone in armature.bones:
    if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(bone.name, "something"):
        armature.delete(bone)
```

And returns the error `'Armature' object has no attribute 'delete'`. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, blender tends to use the term `remove` instead of `delete`. Secondly, the armature doesn't directly store the bones, they are stored in a collection called `edit_bones` (at least, they are when you are in *Edit Mode*, which is what you script does. `bones` is for *Pose Mode*/*Object Mode*, but bones can't be deleted from there).

So, you firstly need to loop over the `edit_bones` instead of `bones` and then use `remove` instead of `delete`.

```
for bone in armature.edit_bones:
    if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(bone.name, "something"): 
        armature.edit_bones.remove(bone)
```

You can easily explore the properties available on the armature using blender's *Python Console*, typing in your code there and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to autocomplete:

```
>>> bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.
                                      animation_data
                                      animation_data_clear(
                                      animation_data_create(
                                      as_pointer(
                                      bl_rna
                                      bones
                                      copy(
                                      deform_method
                                      draw_type
                                      driver_add(
                                      driver_remove(
                                      edit_bones
                                      get(
                                      ghost_frame_end
                                      ghost_frame_start
                                      ghost_size
                                      ghost_step
                                      ghost_type
                                      id_data
                                      is_editmode
                                      is_library_indirect
                                      is_property_hidden(
                                      is_property_readonly(
                                      is_property_set(
                                      is_updated
                                      is_updated_data
                                      items(
                                      keyframe_delete(
                                      keyframe_insert(
                                      keys(
                                      etc....
                                      etc...
                                      etc..
                                      etc.
```

Using this, you would be able to see there is no `delete` method.